# DESIGN PATTERNS - Parsing 4 different JSON files

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I have a problem that I cannot figure out. I have 4 different JSON files for configurations. Some of these files require extra API calls whereas others don't for instance.

4 files

A
B
C
D

**A and B just require.**

A.getConfigs()

B.getConfigs()

**C however requires**

C.getConfigs()

C.getCase()

**D requires**

D.getConfigs()

D.getHeader()

What kind of pattern/object should I use when I also want to be able to call individual methods for C and D?

I could very easily move the getCase and getHeader logic into the client code but then I realized I need to use this logic in multiple places in the application code. So what can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), which aims provide a simplified interface to more complex operations.

I'm taking a bit of liberty here by calling it a facade, as it usually involves wrapping other classes, instead of merely implementing an interface, but I think it still applies.

```java
/* define facade interface */
interface Configurable {
  void configure();
}

/* abstract basic configuration */
abstract class Config 
  implements Configurable
{
  abstract void getConfigs();
  
  void configure() {
    getConfigs();
  }
}
```

```java
/* implementations */
class ConfigA
  extends Config
{
  void getConfigs() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
}

class ConfigB
  extends Config
{
  void getConfigs() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
}

class ConfigC
  extends Config
{
  void getConfigs() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
  
  void getCase() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
  
  /* override configure */
  void configure() {
    getConfigs();
    getCase();
  }
}


class ConfigD
  extends Config
{
  void getConfigs() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
  
  void getHeader() {
    /* do stuff */
  }
  
  /* override configure */
  void configure() {
    getConfigs();
    getHeader();
  }
}
```

```java
/* usage */
class Client
{
  private Config config;
  
  Client(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
  }
  
  void start() {
    config.configure();
    /* do more stuff */
  }
}
```

However, if, as your method names seem to imply, `getConfigs()`, `getCase()` and `getHeader()` should return values that the client needs to operate on then things could get a bit complicated and maybe this pattern doesn't add many benefits.

---

Also, I overlooked that you want to be able to individually call the methods of `C` and `D`, which is still possible with my suggestion, but if you didn't intend to execute them with `getConfigs()` at the same time at all then my idea is probably not what you are looking for.